# Disable capturing in already-compiled regex? (e.g., Perl 5.22+, /n modifier)

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

**Environment:** Perl 5.26.2 x64 on Cygwin x64.

**Question:** after `my $re = qr/...(capturing group).../`, is there any way to use `$re` without capturing into its capturing groups?

**X:** I am matching lines that could either be:

```
#define FOO(X,Y) SomeComplicatedStuff
```

or

```
#define FOO(X,Y) BAR(X,Y)
```

I have a compiled regex `$re` that matches `FOO(X,Y)` and includes numbered capturing groups to split the match into `FOO` and `X,Y`.  I would like to match lines of the second form without having to define a separate regex, e.g., using `m/$re.+$re/`.  This works fine, but I get all the capturing groups of `FOO` when I all I really want are the groups of `BAR`.

**Y:** I thought I could do this in 5.22+ with the `/n` modifier, but I can't get it to work.  MCVE:

```
$ perl -E 'my $re=qr/(foo|bar)/; "foobar" =~ m/$re$re/; say $1, " ", $2;'
foo bar     # as expected

$ perl -E 'my $re=qr/(foo|bar)/; "foobar" =~ m/(?n:$re)$re/; say $1, " ", $2;'
            # I think this should turn off      ^^^  capturing of `foo`
foo bar     # oops - I was hoping for `bar`

$ perl -E 'my $re=qr/(foo|bar)/; "foobar" =~ m/(?n:(foo|bar))$re/; say $1, " ", $2;'
bar         # This works, but I had to inline $re within (?n:...).
```

**Note:** I also tried `\K`:

```
$ perl -E 'my $re=qr/(foo|bar)/; "foobar" =~ m/$re\K$re/; say $1, " ", $2, " ", $&;'
foo bar bar      # was hoping for `bar  bar`
```

**Edit** Forgot to mention — I did look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552850/2877364), but it's not the same problem statement.

Comment: `$re` stringifies to `(?^u:(foo|bar))` which similar to `(?u-imnsx:(foo|bar))`; it sets the flags to those used when the pattern was compiled, and thus turning `/n` off.

Comment: Seems like it works if you avoid using `qr` on `$re`, i.e `$re = "(foo|bar)"`

Comment: I must be missing something but why doesn't `/foo|(bar)/` go?  Like `perl -E'$s=shift||q(foobar); $re = qr{foo|(bar)}; $s =~ /$re$re/; say "$1 -- $2"'` (with optional input)

Comment: `\K` leaves stuff matched left of it out of `$&`, but not out of `$1` and `$2`.

Answer (score 3):

The stringification of `$re` is `(?^u:(foo|bar))`. In other words, it sets the flags to those used when the pattern was compiled, and thus turning `/n` off.

You could use any of the following:

```
my $re = qq/(foo|bar)/;    # Note: Gotta escape `\` that are part of regex escapes.
/(?n:$re)$re/
```

(example of escapes: `qr{(fo\w|ba\w)}` becomes `qq{(fo\\w|ba\\w)}` when using this technique.)

```
my $re = qr/foo|bar/;
/$re($re)/
```

```
my $re = qr/
   (?<foo_or_bar>) ((?<foo_or_bar>))
   (?(DEFINE)
      (?<foo_or_bar>foo|bar)
   )
/x;
/$re/
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the problem, and the first two solution options.  `qq//` would work in my use case.  Would you please add some explanation and an SSCCE of the third option?  Based on perlre's discussion of DEFINE (which I've never used before), shouldn't the first line of the third pattern have a `(?&foo_or_bar)` in it somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found a workaround, but it's certainly not an answer!  I'm posting it here anyway, in case it helps anyone else.  In my particular use case, the match is split in two.  Therefore, using `/g` on the first match and `\G` in the second match does the trick.  Example:

```
$ perl -E '
    my $re=qr/(foo|bar)/;
    my $str = "foo bar";

    $str =~ m/$re/g;         # Match `foo`, and set `pos` (because of /g)
    say "Expecting foo: ", $1;

    $str =~ m/\G.+$re/g;     # \G => skip past `foo`, and check ` bar` against `.+$re`
    say "Hoping for bar: ";
'
Expecting foo: foo
Hoping for bar: bar          # Hooray!
```